# How to send a data to another knockout model?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to send data to another knockout view model.
For example, A user go to a page with list of items. Then per item, there is a link. If the user click the link, The next page will have the value for example. for the list item is number 3. the next page will have 3 as value..

I treid this but failed

```
methods.initialize = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.setupSubscriptions();
    self.update(true);
    Utils.ajaxPost('getMyOrganizations',{"data":""},function(result){
        result = JSON.parse(result);
        if(_.isArray(result)){
            _.each(result,function(obj){
                self.organizations.push([obj["organization_name"],3,3,obj['id']]);
            });
        }
    });

};
methods.setupSubscriptions = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.update.syncWith('selectedOrg',true);
};
```

and the other model,

```
methods.initialize = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.setupSubscriptions();
};
methods.setupSubscriptions = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.update.subscribeTo('selectedOrg', function(newUser){
        if(newUser){
           //Do the logic here
            self.update = true;
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easy ways is to create a new instance of your second view model inside your main View Model as an observable variable and then you can easily communicate between your view models.

Below I am just showing you the logic you can use.

Example :https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/67/

HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:Items">
  <li>
  <span data-bind="text:item">
  </span>
  <a data-bind="click:$parent.LinkClicked,text:'ClickOnME'">

  </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div data-bind="text:MessageFromSecondVM">

</div>
<hr>
<div data-bind="with:SecondVM">
  <h3 data-bind="text:SecondVMVariable">
  </h3>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function FirstViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.SecondVM = ko.observable();
    self.FirstVMVariable = ko.observable();
    self.MessageFromSecondVM = ko.observable();
    self.Items = ko.observableArray([{item:"Item 1" ,value :1},{item:"Item 2" ,value :2},{item:"Item 3" ,value :3}]);

  // you can create a new instance whenever you want in your model
    self.SecondVM(new SecondViewModel());

    self.LinkClicked = function(item){
        self.SecondVM().SecondVMVariable("Value " + item.value + " sent to SecondVM From FirstVM");
    self.SecondVM().Value(item.value);

  }
}
function SecondViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.SecondVMVariable = ko.observable();
    self.Value = ko.observable();
    self.Value.subscribe(function(newValue){
     if(newValue){
     FirstVM.MessageFromSecondVM("Value " + newValue + " was sent back from SecondVM here");
    }
  })
}
var FirstVM = new FirstViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(FirstVM);
```